# c# how to create sample array form json data

Tags: c#, arrays, json

my json

```
[{"m":0},{"m":1},{"m":2},{"m":3},{"m":5}]
```

I need create array

```
[0,1,2,3,5]
```

this is my code but don't work

```
public class vclass
    {
        public int m { get; set; }
    
    }
public class iResponse
    {   
        public List<vclass> m { get; set; }
    }

iResponse result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iResponse>(res);
```

Comment: try JsonConverter.Deserialize<List<vclass>>(res);

Answer (score 0):

```
public class vclass
{
    public int m { get; set; }
}

vclass[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vclass[]>("your json string here");
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any custom classes

```
int[] arr = JArray.Parse(json).Select(ja => (int) ja["m"] ).ToArray(); // or ToList() if you want a list
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need this:

```
var res = @"[{""m"":0},{""m"":1},{""m"":2},{""m"":3},{""m"":5}]";
vclass[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vclass[]>(res);
```

That gives your array.